# Read BLE data using sirikit

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit

Im trying to add Siri integration to my app.

Intended for reading measurements from BLE device. How can I prompt user to turn on Bluetooth and continue the discussion with Siri without ending the session.

Break in the sense going to settings may break the Siri session.

Also I need to know how much a session will be available and how much responses siri can ask back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/) documentation clearly shows, there's no Intent for interacting with BLE devices, so you cannot achieve your goals using Siri.

As for the question regarding how much context Siri can handle/remember: it can remember all answers that were used to populate the required parameters of a specific Intent. Once your Intent extension signals Siri that it is able to handle the intent with the required information by calling the `handle` function of the relevant Intent domain, Siri will forget the previous context.

Comment: As my app is reading some continues data. Can it be included in workouts intent?, hope BLE is not a concern

Comment: All `SiriKit` intents use a small set of sentences as their triggers and only provide a fixed set of information to your intents extension, but as long as those both fit your needs, you should be good to go with a Workout intent. However, bear in mind that your app will need to handle the background execution to continuously communicate with the BLE peripheral, the Workouts intent provides no means for this.

Comment: my BLE service is to transfer some information that may require 20 mins. It is one time sync.

Comment: In that case you can only start the transfer using Siri, you definitely cannot make Siri wait 20mins for your intent handler to return, so the situation is pretty much the same as if you needed continuous connection: your app needs to handle the background execution while communicating with the BLE device.

Comment: Thanks for your support. One more thing. If that transfer takes only 40 secs can Intent UI wait for that much time.

Comment: Yes, your intent handler doesn't need to immediately return, it can even execute network requests before returning, which might take a minute or two. There's no hard guideline of when will the system cancel your intent handler, but according to my experience if your intent handler doesn't call the completion handler in a few minutes, Siri won't wait longer.